# How to use React native select box

Tags: react-native

I was working on an IosApp using React Native. I need a form element like select box in HTML. Is there any ways to achieve the same in React Native Form components?

Answer (score 9):

Probably the closest to what you want that comes bundled with React Native is http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker.html

The Picker component will give you a tumbler thing on iOS and a dropdown on Android

Alternatively maybe this 3rd party component is closer to what you want: https://github.com/bulenttastan/react-native-list-popover

People are creating new components for React Native all the time, a good place to search from them is: https://react.parts/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something that works both on Android and IOS . I would recommend this. Feasible solution.
https://github.com/gs-akhan/react-native-select

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to install select-option using npm:

```
npm i react-native-option-select --save
```

Then you must include

```
import DropDown, {
  Select,
  Option,
  OptionList,
} from 'react-native-option-select';
```